# Not to check checkbox on click..but to check on condition

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am trying to check the checkbox on some condition which is to be performed on other activitiy, On the click of the checkbox containing listview. I'll click on my listview containg checkbox which take me to other activity where I'll fill the form and move back to my listview with a status depending on which I'll check the checkbox. For this, I am using static arraylist to store data of listview on which I got success status and using this arraylist checkbox is checked. Here is my code:

```
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        final FinalSubmitItem rowItem = getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {  
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customview_finalsubmit_itemdetails, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();  
            holder.txtItemType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ItemtypeFinal);
            holder.txtCountry = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtcountryFinal);    
            holder.txtSerial = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemNumberFinal);
            holder.chck = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheck);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtItemType.setText(rowItem.getItemType());
            holder.txtCountry.setText(rowItem.getItemCountry());
            holder.txtSerial.setText(rowItem.getItemNo());              

                 if(position == 0){
                    holder.chck.setChecked(false);
                 }
                for(int i=0; i<checkedInfo.size(); i++){
                    if(rowItem.getItemNo().equals(checkedInfo.get(i).getItemSerialVerified())){
                        rowItem.setItemCheck(true);
                        }
                    }
                if(rowItem.isItemCheck()){
                    holder.chck.setChecked(true);
                }


            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String itemType = rowItem.getItemType();
                    String itemCountry = rowItem.getItemCountry();
                    String itemSerial = rowItem.getItemNo();
                    int itemTypeId = rowItem.getItemId();
                    int pickupId = rowItem.getPickupId();
                    Intent inn = new Intent(context, FinalSubmitDetails.class);
                    inn.putExtra("itemType", itemType);
                    inn.putExtra("itemCountry", itemCountry);
                    inn.putExtra("itemSerial", itemSerial);
                    inn.putExtra("itemId", itemTypeId);
                    inn.putExtra("pickupId", pickupId);
                    context.startActivity(inn);
                }
            } );
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        return convertView;
    }
```

In other activity:

```
            if(response.contains("Success.")){
                serialNumberVerf = serialNumber;
                itemIdVerified = itemId;
                actionIdVerified = actionId;
                ItemCheckedInfo info = new ItemCheckedInfo();
                info.setActionIdVerified(actionIdVerified);
                info.setItemIdVerified(itemIdVerified);
                info.setItemSerialVerified(serialNumberVerf);
                checkedInfo.add(info);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            onBackPressed();
```

But its not working and I have declared this arraylist in a class in which customview class is declared.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And why is the ArrayList static?

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice edited..please check

Comment: neither its checking the checkbox nor its performing multiple checkbox selection..I want both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it this way..just a single line edited in getview() method:

```
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(inn, 1);
```

And on success did this:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("position", position);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

At last in main activity did this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            int positionResult=data.getIntExtra("position",0);
            itemInfo.get(positionResult).setItemCheck(true);
            item.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener%29)

[Edit]

**Actually i need to perform things on click of listview..thatswhy i didn't use it**
You can override `onItemClickListener` for it.

Comment: Actually i need to perform things on click of listview..thatswhy i didn't use it

Comment: convertView.setOnClickListener doing the same thing

Comment: For this, you need to set listener on the checkbox.

Comment: I just want to check it on condition..I don't have any reason to call listener